# Como encontrar um endereço pela latitude e longitude

Tags: javascript, mobile, google-maps, gps, geolocalização

Como eu consigo obter o endereço por extenso de uma geolocalização, 
ex:

```
Lat. 37.386196601958
Lon. -121.964346639
```

(Rua tal, Bairro tal, cep: tal)

Comment: Pergunta muito ampla. Tem alguma tentativa?

Comment: Desculpe, não faço nem ideia, no google só devolve respostas em lat e lon. Eu uso uma API para geolocalização e uma API do Google Places que me devolve os endereços. Só que a API do Google Places as vezes não devolve o endereço completo da Geolocalização, então vou ter que procurar manualmente para compor minhas informações de endereço por extendo!!! Fui claro?

Comment: Então é google api que vai usar... Faça perguntas mais claras, a sua pergunta nem informa que API vai usar, estavamos presumindo que fosse alguma api mobile, como o GPS nativo.

Comment: Mas amigo, a questão não é como estou obtendo a geolocalização, eu poderia estar usando a API de Geolocalização nativa do HTML5 que não faria diferença, a questão é que preciso do endereço por extenso! E não gostaria de usar outra API como Google Maps por que elas tem um limite de requisições diarias, logo a ser cobradas. Queria saber se existe algo nativo do html 5 ou alguma api em javascript ou até mesmo api free da web.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) de geolocalização fornecida pelo Google:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/output?parameters
```

O `output` define o formato de resposta, podendo ser JSON ou XML. Os `parameters` dependem do tipo de informação que está buscando, maiores detalhes podem ser encontrados na [documentação](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro). Uma busca simples por latitude e longitude poderia ser feita da seguinte forma:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=37.386196601958,-121.964346639
```

Comment: Bah legal @Renan, esta eu não havia usado ainda, e o bom é que não precisa consumir da minha margem de "cotas" diárias. Acho que vou usar esta!

Answer (score 3):

Se desejar uma solução OpenSource/Free, utilize o serviço [reverse do OpenStreet](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Reverse_Geocoding). Ficaria assim um request ajax:

```
  reqwest({
      url: 'http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?',
      method: 'get',
      crossOrigin: true,
      type: 'json',
      data: {
          format: 'json',
          lat: latitude,
          lon: longitude,
          addressdetails: 1,
          'accept-language': 'pt-BR',
          zoom: 18
      }
  }).then(function (response) {
        console.info(response);
    msg_el.innerHTML = response.display_name;
  }).fail(function (err, msg) {
      console.info(err, msg);
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/LdpcyL6o/